# Как в переменную Postgresql присвоить запрос?

Tags: postgresql

Каким образом можно в переменную присвоить запрос?
По аналогии как в mssql

> @result=Select * from dual where a1=a2;

Реальный пример

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_test ()
 RETURNS varchar(1) AS
$BODY$
 DECLARE
 outinfo varchar(1);
 test text;
 BEGIN
    test = select count(*) from table;
    if test>0 THEN
    outinfo := 'y';
    else
    outinfo := 'n';
    END if;
    return outinfo;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: в языке запросов postgresql переменных нет. Они есть только внутри pl/sql кода (это отдельный язык внутри postgresql). Те же самые задачи, которые вы привыкли решать с помощью переменных в mssql в постгресе решаются совершенно другими способами. поэтому уточните задачу, для чего именно вам понадобилась переменная

Comment: plpgsql, мне нужно присвоить значение запроса для дальнейшей работы с выходным значение, а точнее сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: ну если в plsql то `select X from DUAL ... into Result`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы переписал вашу функцию следующим образом:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stoppagelog2ora () RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        _count BIGINT = 0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT INTO _count count(*) FROM mssql_startrepltoora;
        RETURN _count > 0;
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: @Егор под вопросом есть ссылка "править" пишите всю информацию которая его касается непосредственно в тексте вопроса. Читать это в комментариях, да еще и к ответу, который могут удалить, никто не будет